# Python-Pandas While loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am having some trouble with the DataFrame and while loop:

```
A     B
5     10
5     10
10    5
```

I am trying to have a while loop that:

```
while (Column A < Column B):
    Column A = Column A + (Column B / 2)
    Column B = Column B / 2
```

Any ideas how to do this.

Comment: It would be a good idea to try writing some code at first as an attempt to solve that problem and then post that code here in order for us to comment on it.

Comment: While you are at it post the expected answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Next time try to solve it instead of ask it directly. You will learn more:) Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'A': [5,5,10], 'B': [10,10,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
Out[]:
A   B
0   5  10
1   5  10
2  10   5

rows = df.shape[0]
i = 0
while i < rows and df.loc[i,'A'] < df.loc[i,'B']:
    df.loc[i,'A'] += df.loc[i,'B']/2
    df.loc[i,'B'] = df.loc[i,'B']/2
    i += 1
df
Out[]:
A   B
0   10  5
1   10  5
2   10  5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorise this calculation to avoid explicit loops:

```
mask = df['A'] < df['B']

df.loc[mask, 'A'] = df['A'] + df['B'] / 2
df.loc[mask, 'B'] = df['B'] / 2

print(df)

#       A    B
# 0  10.0  5.0
# 1  10.0  5.0
# 2  10.0  5.0
```