# How to use while with loc as condition?

Tags: python

### `import pandas as pd`

```
x = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Igor\\Desktop\\Visão Geral - Carteira FII - IGOR.xlsx",sheet_name = "dividendos")
y = pd.DataFrame(x)
y
```

---

out:

```
Stock   DIVIDEND    Payment Month
0   BRCR11  4.50    2022-01-14  2022-01-01
1   BLMG11  15.30   2022-01-15  2022-01-01
2   BRCO11  10.71   2022-01-07  2022-01-01
3   BTAL11  9.13    2022-01-26  2022-01-01
4   BTRA11  10.68   2022-01-31  2022-01-01
5   BTLG11  10.80   2022-01-25  2022-01-01
```

---

```
t = 0
while y.loc[t] != "":
    print(t)
t = t + 1
```

---

out:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: What are you expecting that to do?  It's not at all clear.

Comment: You are not incrementing t within the while loop. See here for an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740960/python-pandas-while-loop

Comment: @Nick rows = y.shape[0]
t = 0
while t < rows:
    t = t + 1
print(t)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are new to Python and Pandas. look what is `type(df.loc[0])`. It is  `pandas.core.series.Series`=, and cannot be compare to a string.
Using of `while` is not common in Python and even less with Pandas.
are you looking for an empty "cell">
Probably you are looking to something like `print(df[df['Stock'].isna()])`
I am not sure which columns you assume to be empty.